# JQuery Remove White Space on Blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I have a form input field for user postcodes to be entered but I need the value to have no white spaces. I have a JQuery validation script that I want to delete the white space on blur but I've tried several solutions and none of them work. Any ideas how this can be acheived? Here is the validation I'm using:

```
// Postcode Validation
$('#regpostcode').blur(function()
{
$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/^\s+$/,"")); // THIS IS THE LINE I'M INTERESTED IN
var regpostcode=$(this).val();
if(regpostcode.length < 5){
    $('.regPostcodeStatus').html("Please Enter Your Actual Postcode").removeClass("success").addClass("error");
    regpostcodeok = 2;
}
else if(regpostcode.length > 7){
    $('.regPostcodeStatus').html("Please Enter Your Actual Postcode").removeClass("success").addClass("error");
    regpostcodeok = 2;
}
else{
    $('.regPostcodeStatus').html("Thank You").removeClass("error").addClass("success");
    regpostcodeok = 1;
}
});
```

This returns "Please Enter Your Actual Postcode" as obviously the length with the space in is over 7 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want

```
$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\s/g,""));
```

I removed the `^` (start of string) and the `$` (end of string) and I added the [`g` flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_Searching_With_Flags) to match all spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Your current REGEX anchors to the beginning and end of the pattern. In other words, it will match only a string that is formed entirely of space characters, nothing else.

Instead, you need:

```
.replace(/\s/g, "")
```

The `g` refers to the global modifier, so it will remove all whitespace in the string, whether they're consecutive or not.